# Assigning input from a GUI to a variable in Powershell

Tags: user-interface, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to create a GUI for one of the scripts I'm running that is really just a fancy way to get input from a user and feed it into a variable that will be used later on in the script. However, when I enter anything into the text input field, it doesn't assign to the variable unless I go to the specific line in the code and run it by itself. What am I doing wrong?

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "File Path"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "Go for gold!"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Abort! It's a trap!"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the full file path:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

I found a solution on here that suggested changing the variable to $global, but that did nothing. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go with a standard VB InputBox:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please enter your name",$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

It's dirty, but it's essentially what you're looking for I think, and it's far fewer lines of code than making your own Windows Form. If you want to hide the console output of loading Microsoft.VisualBasic, then you can do one of two things:

1. Prepend [System.Reflection.Assembly] with [void], which will tell the console to ignore the output
2. Pipe it in to Out-Null, and you'll achieve the same effect

One alternative is you can wait for the Windows Form to close (the code should stop until the window opened by $objForm.ShowDialog() has closed, too), and then grab the text out of $objTextBox.Text.

If all you really want is for someone to put in a folder path or file path, though, then this method is by far the easiest to implement and validate:

```
$vbShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$folder = $vbShell.BrowseForFolder(0x00,"Enter your custom text here",0x01)
$path = $folder.Self.Path
```

Here's the documentation for the Shell object from Microsoft, too, so that you can get the BrowseForFolder method to work the way you want it to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope this helps!
It's a very familiar window... Employed in more Windows applications than I care to count.